# Pickle load error: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system

Tags: python-3.x, path, operating-system, load, pickle

I ran a python program on Windows 10 which generated a .p file with pickle to save the data structure. When I tried to open this file on a Linux machine I got this issue:

```
     25     """
     26     if os.path.isfile(filename):
---> 27         list_to_open = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
     28         return list_to_open
     29     return None

~/Applications/miniconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   1023         if not self._flavour.is_supported:
   1024             raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
-> 1025                                       % (cls.__name__,))
   1026         self._init()
   1027         return self

NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system
```

Path has been used in the script, so the separator might be compatible to any OS ('/', '\', etc.). Is there another way to load this pickle file on Linux? Or is it possible to change all paths from WindowsPath to PosixPath inside the .p file?